# Expo iOS app not showing on full screen Can any one have Idea?

Tags: react-native, expo

I just started a build on expo IOS, when i am running on android device its showing perfectly fine but when i run on IOS emulator its show something as you can see in the picture[This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azxr3.png)

I have tried to give it custom width but not worked

Comment: post full code first

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response I have fixed it by setting dimension dynamically